# Chartjs chart broke when using Pagedjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, pagedjs

I am using Chartjs & Paged.js to print pages.

[image: Before paged.preview]

Everything is fine but when I call this code, the charts disappear:

```javascript
  let flow = paged.preview().then((flow) => {
    console.log("Rendered", flow.total, "pages.");
  });
```

Are these two packages not getting along?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried using a normal canvas and rendered a rectangle to it. Before calling `paged.preview()` it is fine, then it seems like Paged.js clears the canvas.

Comment: I was wondering if you ever found a solution to this one? I have the same problem but just with amcharts5 javascript. It seems like any rendered js is removed by Paged.js

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't find any solution in the end.

Comment: Was able to get it working by implementing a custom handler which triggers the chartjs rendering on the `afterRendered` hook in paged.js. Feels a bit hacky, but hope it helps. https://pagedjs.org/documentation/10-handlers-hooks-and-custom-javascript/

Comment: Any news on this one? Also paged js is not working even with regular canvases.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this after help by the good people at https://pagedjs.org/

Add this to your `<head>`-tag:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pagedjs/dist/paged.polyfill.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now in your `body`, add the following Paged.js extension:

```
<body>
<div id="yourchart"></div>
<script>

 function generateChart() {
    // code for chart here.
 }

  class myChartCreator extends Paged.Handler {
            constructor(chunker, polisher, caller) {
                super(chunker, polisher, caller);
            }

            afterRendered(pages) {
              
               // add your chart generating code/calls here:

               generateChart();
               someOtherFunction();

               // some even longer running functions.
               return Promise.resolve(
                    someLongRunningStuff()
               );
               ...
             }
        }
        Paged.registerHandlers(myChartCreator);


</script>
</body>
```

The key is adding your chart code/calls to generate charts to the `afterRendered` method.

It works perfectly with both `Chart.js` and `amcharts5`.